Why do I get yocto build error "Feature 'cfg/efi.scc' not found, this will cause configuration failures"?
I'm trying to write a meta laterfor scarthgap and build only the kernel for a custom board.
I have added all the configurations but it seems efi causes some erros in build despite following the documentation.
conf/machine/custom.conf
...
...
MACHINE_FEATURES = "acpi alsa bluetooth efi keyboard pci qemu-usermode rtc screen usbhost vfat wifi opengles opencl hwh264dec hwh264enc"

...
...
EFI_PROVIDER ?= "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "systemd", "systemd-boot", "grub-efi", d)}"
...
...

The build causes:
MACHINE=custom bitbake linux-yocto
...

ERROR: linux-yocto-5.10.184+git-r0 do_kernel_metadata: Feature 'cfg/efi.scc' not found, this will cause configuration failures.
ERROR: linux-yocto-5.10.184+git-r0 do_kernel_metadata: Check the SRC_URI for meta-data repositories or directories that may be missing
ERROR: linux-yocto-5.10.184+git-r0 do_kernel_metadata: Set KERNEL_DANGLING_FEATURES_WARN_ONLY to ignore this issue
ERROR: linux-yocto-5.10.184+git-r0 do_kernel_metadata: ExecutionError('/home/user1/workspace/yocto-scarthgap-5.0/build/tmp/work/custom-poky-linux/linux-yocto/5.10.184+git/temp/run.do_kernel_metadata.2434247', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user1/workspace/yocto-scarthgap-5.0/build/tmp/work/custom-poky-linux/linux-yocto/5.10.184+git/temp/log.do_kernel_metadata.2434247
...

Why is this happening? I do not find any file named efi.scc in poky:
user1@PC-1:~/workspace/yocto-scarthgap-5.0/poky$ find . -name efi.scc
user1@PC-1:~/workspace/yocto-scarthgap-5.0/poky$ 


user1@PC-1:~/workspace/yocto-scarthgap-5.0/poky$ grep -nri efi.scc
documentation/kernel-dev/advanced.rst:572:   include cfg/efi.scc
meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc:36:KERNEL_FEATURES:append = " ${@bb.utils.contains('MACHINE_FEATURES', 'efi', 'cfg/efi.scc', '', d)}"

How is this supposed to work? Is poky feature itself broken?

If you enable EFI, how do you expect to get the necessary description and keys? If you don't want to use secure boot, disable EFI instead. Kernel Metadata Syntax

But it works with default qemu recipies without the file. Its only showing this issue with my MACHINE. Why is it working for default example of quemu?
